# IEEEtranbib, bibentry, hyperref - Simple example?

Tags: hyperref, ieeetran, bibentry

I am trying to make `IEEEtranbib` work with `bibentry` and `hyperref`, but I am stuck.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran/IEEEtran}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
  CTLuse_forced_etal       = "yes",
  CTLmax_names_forced_etal = "4",
  CTLnames_show_etal       = "2",
  CTLdash_repeated_names   = "no"
}
@article{myentry,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    url     = "https://dwqdhqwjkdhqkjdhqd.dwqdq/djkqwb",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}
\newcommand{\fullcite}[1]{\begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{#1}\end{NoHyper}}

\begin{document}

\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}

\nobibliography*

A citation: \cite{myentry}

Inline entry: \begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{myentry}\end{NoHyper}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranbib/IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEtranbib/IEEEabrv,\jobname}{}

\end{document}
```

Error when compiling:

```
Runaway argument?
\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing G.~D. Greenwade, ``The {C}omprehensive {\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \BR@c@bibitem was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.30
```

I have tried tons of combinations of extra `renewcommand` or `makeatletter`, such as:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibentry[1]{\nocite{#1}{\frenchspacing
     \@nameuse{BR@r@#1\@extra@b@citeb}}}
\makeatother
```

Could someone provide a simple example on how to make `IEEEtranbib` work with `bibentry` and `hyperref` when bib entries have `url` fields?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by setting up a macro called `\fullcite` that invokes `\bibentry`? What's wrong about "ordinary" `\cite`-type commands?

Comment: @Mico I want a full citation in the text, which is what bibentry does, and the NoHyper environment is to avoid hyperref linking to the bibentry instead of the reference (found on another question here). I am open to any suggestion!

Comment: I suspect it's due to the fact that the URL is too long and it cannot hyphenate it. Moreover, it seems that bibentry does not care whether the URL is enclosed in `\href`, `\hyperlink`, `\url`, `\hyperref`.

Comment: Found a discussion about the issue at https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/mailman/message/9168466/